# Questions about atomic property in multithread operations, which case should we use atomic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, atomic

What I have tried:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int count;
```

in global queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i ++) {
        self.count ++;
    }
});
```

in main queue:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i ++) {
    self.count ++;
}
```

After these operations finished, the log shows count value is below 20000. because of Data Race (Xcode point it out).

Then I change property from `nonatomic` to `atomic`, value still below 20000, without Data Race (Xcode didn't point it out)

So , I have some questions about `atomic`, which case should we use `atomic`? which is the best way to use `atomic`?

Comment: Remember that `self.count++` is really `[self setCount:[self count] + 1];`.

Comment: @rmaddy so, does it exist locks inside setter method? which kind of lock?

Comment: @KZ.matt Marked as a dupe, but wanted to point you to the specific detail.  What you need is *transactional integrity*, which `atomic` does not provide.  In effect, you're looking at the firstName/lastName synchronicity issue.

Comment: @KZ.matt atomic is thread safe yes, in one sense but not the other. The way in which it is safe is that a getter will return to you a full valid object. The way it is not thread safe is that it is not necessarily locking or protecting the associated property getter and setter while a get or set is taking place, no. So you will still have race issues, but no issues when getting an object / value. This post will help you understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/589392/870565

Comment: @KZ.matt To fully understand this imagine an atomic property that holds a very large object where the setter takes about 2 seconds. If you call the getter right after the setter, you will get the previous object, or possibly get an object when the setter concludes. If the property was defined as non-atomic then you might get a corrupted object since the deallocation and re-allocation of the previous and new object respectively have not finished yet... So yes, you will still have race issue in both cases, but atomic is safer, though slower in a more complex setup